# MySQL design: A query to get collection with most actions within a given timeframe

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table called `topic` that has a column named `like_count`.

Is it possible to write a query on that table to ask "give me the top 10 most liked topics in the past 7 days", meaning the 10 topics that have had the most likes on them in the past 7 days, without creating an additional auditing table?

I was thinking of doing this by creating some auditing table such as `topic_like_audit` that would have just two columns: `topic_id` and `created_at`. Every time the topic with that ID got liked, a new record would be stored in the audit table. Then I can write a query that aggregates all results within the past 7 days using the `created_at` column, and ranks by the ones that have the most amount of records in that timeframe.

But I can't imagine that being a scalable solution... it may work in the short term, but that surely must be bad when you have topics that have millions, or even hundreds of thousands of likes.

Any good, standard solutions on doing something like this, or is my approach sufficient? P.S. I'm a DB noob.

Comment: the suggested audit table with appropriate indexing should be workable. if you do imagine it proceeding into millions of rows you could partition it (perhaps by month or year?) and/or consider archiving rows that are not relevant to current site operation.

Comment: @Used_By_Already You actually make a really good point, could just delete records older than a certain timeframe to reduce table size. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: by the way to solve `"give me the top 10 most liked topics in the past 7 days"` you DO need datetime information for each like

Comment: Yes, indeed. I modified my question to add `created_at` field for the audit table records.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you can tolerate your insert to be a little slower or not .

What you can do is , initially you can generate data for top ten topics by some query. 
You can maintain this list in mysql or any caching layer .It would be good if you maintain at caching level , because you would want your retrieval to be fast .

At each insertion of like of new topic , you could compare the current topic like with the topic with minimum like in your list , if current is larger , you can swap them . You can use priority queue as data structure for this thing , leading to O(logn) time .

This process can be delayed further as you could have eventually consistent system instead of consistent system . You could push this to queue which can be further process by workers .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you can't tell when a "like" occurred?  With out tying each "like" (or batch of "likes") to a datetime (or just day), you cannot do it.

When a "like" occurs, store it in a table (`TodaysLikes`) with `topic` and `datetime`.  At the end of each day, summarize yesterday's data into a Summary table (`LikesSummary`) with `topic`, `date` (not datetime), and `count`.  Then remove them from `TodaysLikes`.

Then this gets the top 10:

```
SELECT topic, SUM(count) AS likes
    FROM LikesSummary
    WHERE date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
    ORDER BY likes DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

A further optimization is not to directly bump `like_count` in as the "like" occurs, but do that as part of the nightly summarization.  (This implies the `like_count` is not up-to-the-second, but only counts through last night.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Had already solved this, but good advice on the multiple tables. May be a good idea if I want to keep storage size small. However, for the time being, I want to keep all records for historical purposes.